# Separate Number from Word and return new List in Python

Tags: python, string, concatenation

```
new_list = []
pattern = re.compile("([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)")

for i, x in enumerate(my_list):
    if (re.match(r"([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+)", x)):
        result = pattern.match(x)
        #result = result.group(1) + ' ' + result.group(2)
        new_list.append(result.group(1))
        new_list.append(result.group(2))
        i = i + 2
        new_list = new_list + my_list[i:]

return new_list
```

Current Output:

```
Input: ['2fee', 'lmao', '222wow']

Output: ['2', 'fee', '222', '222wow', '222', 'wow']
```

Desired Output:

```
['2', 'fee', 'lmao', '222', 'wow']
```

How Can I achieve this output? Thank you very much

Comment: What happens if you just leave out the two lines `i = i + 2` and `new_list = new_list + my_list[i:]`?

Comment: will the numbers always be contiguous (i.e., together as one block)? Will the numbers always be before the letters?

Comment: @mkrieger1 then it returns ['2', 'fee', '222', 'wow']. It is missing the "lmao" in the middle

Comment: You should use `[0-9]*` (*zero* or more digits) instead of `[0-9]+` (*one* or more digits).

Comment: So you could have, say, `1a23bc`? What output do you want in that case?

Comment: One more question: do you really want only ASCII digits and letters here? If I had, say, `2fée`, would you really want to match `'2f'` and `'e'` as two separate words (and then split the first one in half), while skipping the `'é'`?

Comment: @abarnert I was essentially just trying to separate any numbers from words, regardless of the placement of the numbers (none of the input letters will be accented/have any modification). So, for "1a23bc," I would want ['1', 'a', '23', 'bc']. Fortunately, the code from jpp below worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby` with `str.isdigit`:

```
from itertools import groupby

L = ['2fee', 'lmao', '222wow']

res = [''.join(j) for strng in L for _, j in groupby(strng, key=str.isdigit)]

# ['2', 'fee', 'lmao', '222', 'wow']
```

Note this will split every instance of numbers appearing in a string. For example, `'1a23bc'` will be split into `'1'`, `'a'`, `'23'`, `'bc'`.

Comment: The question seems a bit unclear about what's supposed to happen if the numbers are not contiguous. If the OP wants to turn `'1a23bc'` into `'1', 'a', '23', 'bc'`, this is probably the nicest way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, try:

```
import re
input = ['2fee', 'lmao', '222wow']
output = []
for s in input:
    output.extend(t for t in re.split('(\d+)', s) if t)
print output
```